# How can I make [attr.src] work in angular 9?

Tags: angular

I have simple question, I'm using the following tag in the template:

```html
<img [attr.src]="evaluatePicPath(trip)" alt=""  *ngIf="pic_file_name != null">
```

I'm calling this method after sending some data to server, after sending I want to
see the picture on the screen, this is where I send the data by post:

```js
addTrip(tripForm:NgForm) {        
     let newTrip = new Trip(tripForm.value.newName, this.picFileName);
       this.tripService.addTrip(newTrip)      
      .subscribe(
        (val) => {            
            this.returnedTripId = val;                        
        },
        response => {            
        },
        () => {   
            evaluatePicPath(newTrip )               
        });  
  }
```

And  this is the most important method:

```js
evaluatePicPath(trip: Trip) {                   
   let url = AppComponent.API + "/files/" + trip.id + "/" + trip.pic_file_name;          
   return url;     
}
```

The problem is that the pic shown only if I refresh the page F5. I need a way to show
the pic after I added the object to the server.
Thanks!

Comment: Why `[attr.src]` and not just `[src]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve it:

```js
export class MyComponent {
   API = AppComponent.API
}
```

```html
<img [src]="API + "/files/" + trip.id + "/" + trip.pic_file_name" alt=""  *ngIf="trip">
```

Comment: If it doesn't, please show the code which sets the values of `trip` and `pic_file_name` which are mentioned in the piece `<img [attr.src]="evaluatePicPath(trip)" alt=""  *ngIf="pic_file_name != null">`

Comment: I have changed to src but no effect, can you explain what do you mean by export class MyComponent {
   API = AppComponent.API
}

Comment: There is not change in the pic it's new evaluatePicPath method do it

Comment: I tried to do what you suggest but the "" causes problems

Comment: I see `evaluatePicPath` is executed as a callback of the `finally` block of subscription. Are you sure `evaluatePicPath` is executed? it depends on the `this.tripService.addTrip` implementation which I don't see

Comment: It's doen't matter if the method is running or not cause it is not changing the value in the src

Comment: your solution almost work, I mean I make it to work with concating the string inside the src but still doesn't work

Comment: It might me that the solution work, cause I have different problem failing to load the file, I'll open a new question and get back to this one. TOUGH

Comment: I see `*ngIf="pic_file_name != null"`. if `evaluatePicPath` would not be executed, `pic_file_name` would be null and the image would not be displayed.

Comment: while I feel I don't have a full picture and might be missing smg which you see in the full source code (:

Comment: pic_file_name  is not null don't worry

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68592019/i-just-tried-to-read-file-in-spring-boot-so-why-im-getting-error-java-lang-run

Comment: I added new question if It solved then this will mark as solved